# C programming, GSL vector library, error: incompatible type for argument 1 of 'gsl_rng_uniform'

Tags: c, gsl

I'm programming in Code Blocks on Windows OS. I had to use some of the GSL libraries in the code below, but I get an error on line 13, incompatible type for argument 1 of 'gsl_rng_uniform

```
double randomBR = gsl_rng_uniform(r)*360+6;
```

and I don't know how to fix it. Under the error message, there is note Line 150 in the gsl_rng.h file showing: "expected 'const struct gsl_rng *' but argument is of type 'double' ".

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <gsl_vector.h>
#include <gsl_rng.h>

int main()
{
gsl_vector*vec=gsl_vector_alloc(100);

double z, max, min, r;
int k=100, i, pos;

for (i=0; i<k; i++){
    double randomBR = gsl_rng_uniform(r)*360+6;
    z=((int)(gsl_rng_uniform)(r)*360+6);
    gsl_vector_set(vec, i, z);
}

max=gsl_vector_max(vec);
pos_vector_max_index(vec);
min=gsl_vector_min)(vec);
pos_vector_min_index(vec);

if (max == 360)
{
    printf("Max number generated in box %d", pos);
}

if (max < 366)
{
    printf("Max number is %f, position %d", max, pos);
}

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Using value of uninitialized variable having automatic storage duration, which is indeterminate, invokes *undefined behavior*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function prototype is

```
double gsl_rng_uniform (const gsl_rng * r)
```

Clearly it requires a const gsl_rng*, not a double.
Read more about the GSL documentation, you have to get a rng by initialized it first, using gsl_rng_alloc:

```
gsl_rng * r = gsl_rng_alloc (gsl_rng_taus);
```

Then you pass that gsl_rng r to the uniform function to get random numbers you want.

Try to read the docs here:

http://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/manual/html_node/Random-number-generator-initialization.html#Random-number-generator-initialization

http://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/manual/html_node/Sampling-from-a-random-number-generator.html

Answer (score 0):

According to [GNU Scientific Library – Reference Manual: Sampling from a random number generator](https://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/manual/html_node/Sampling-from-a-random-number-generator.html), `gsl_rng_uniform()` will take `const gsl_rng * r`, and it won't accept `double`, which is the type of `r`.

Initialize a random number generator via [`gsl_rng_alloc()`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/manual/html_node/Random-number-generator-initialization.html) and pass the initialized random number generator.